# Content Control - copy Entered Text Field to Header

Tags: microsoft-word

**Goal:**

We have a TEXT field content control which we ask the user of the FORM to enter a Last Name.

This last name is used in a top of the other pages so when faxed or emailed the document Page 2/3/4/5 all have the Last name on the top right corner.

**Issue:**

We cannot seem to find a content control which we can name "last_name" and then have that same control on the top of every page. So when we edit page 1 "Last Name" it is automatically entered into all of the other controls called "last_name"

**Use Case:**

We do not wish to re-type the same information several times. But wish to enter the last name one time and it is copied into Text fields elsewhere in a form document.

Answer (score 1):

The way to achieve this with control controls is to link them to Custom XML which is stored with your document. Custom XML is a little hard to work with directly, so luckily Microsoft Word added a "shortcut". They included fifteen built-in mapped content controls which are linked to the document properties.

1. Choose the Insert menu
2. Click **Quick Parts**.
3. Click **Document Properties**.
4. Click to insert a content control linked to one of these properties
   e.g Author.

If you insert several of these content controls, modify one of them and click somewhere else then all of them are updated automatically. Its good to note that the document property that the controls are linked to are also updated at the same time.

You can rename the content control by going to the Developer Tab, enabling Design Mode and changing the name under properties. The linked behavior still remains intact.

If you want to link the control to more than fifteen properties or do not wish to affect the document properties then you will need to setup your own custom XML property. This is not so easy, however one of the Microsoft MVP created a [great program](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/cc_var_bm_doc_prop_tools_addin.html) to help with that.